# Idiomatic equivalent of following Clojure code

Tags: clojure

Is there any special form or function in Clojure which is an equivalent of:

```
(defn foo [ob col f] 
  (reduce 
     #(f %1 %2) 
     ob col))
```

Basically something like doto but working on Clojure data-structures not on mutable java objects.

Comment: As Leonid points out below, your function is just `reduce` with the arguments in a different order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but it may be simplified to:

```
(reduce f ob coll)
```